# Dynamic radio button with self-post using PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, web, radio-button

I'm drawing data from a MySQL database that dynamically places a question with 4-5 radio button choices for the answer. These radio buttons all belong to the same group, $quest_name. The first pass of the while statement will create 4 radio buttons belonging to radio group "question_1".

It creates 30-40 of these questions on a page, each with 4 radio buttons. I want the user to fill in all there answers and the page to post back to itself with the users answers still selected and then display if they were correct or not (functionality I still have to add).

I'm trying to follow http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_complete.asp as an example, but use a dynamically created radio button name instead.

This is what I have thus far:

```
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"> 

            <?php

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                // output data of each row
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $quest_num = $row["id"];
                    $question = $row["question"];
                    $option_1 = $row["option_1"];
                    $option_2 = $row["option_2"];
                    $option_3 = $row["option_3"];
                    $option_4 = $row["option_4"];
                    $option_5 = $row["option_5"];
                    $answer = $row["answer"];
                    $quest_name = "question_" . $row["id"];

                    echo "(" . $quest_num . ") " . $question . "<br>";
            ?>


                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name=<?php echo $quest_name ?>
                        <?php if (isset(echo $quest_name) && echo $quest_name == echo $option_1) echo "checked"; ?>
                        value=<?php echo $option_1 ?>><?php echo $option_1 ?>
                    </label>
                    <br>

                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name=<?php echo $quest_name ?>
                        value=<?php echo $option_2 ?>><?php echo $option_2 ?>
                    </label>
                    <br>

                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name=<?php echo $quest_name ?>
                        value=<?php echo $option_3 ?>><?php echo $option_3 ?>
                    </label>
                    <br>

                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name=<?php echo $quest_name ?>
                        value=<?php echo $option_4 ?>><?php echo $option_4 ?>
                    </label>
                    <br>
                    <br>

            <?php 
                }
            } else {
                echo "0 results";
            }

            $conn->close();
    ?>

            <input type="submit">
        </form>
```

The part causing me grief so far is:

```
 <?php if (isset(echo $quest_name) && echo $quest_name == echo $option_1) echo "checked"; ?>
```

I have also tried:

```
 <?php if (isset($quest_name) && $quest_name == $option_1) echo "checked"; ?>
```

and:

```
 <?php echo (isset($quest_name) && $quest_name == $option_1) ? "checked" : ""; ?>
```

How do you post back to the same page what they've selected? Like in this case I'm trying to say if "question_1" is set and "question_1" is equal to "converter" (the first radio button option) then have it checked when submit button is clicked.

I'm not that good at web development, but I'm trying to create a website to help my fellow electrical technician classmates.

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT :**

Using this line of code fixed the issue:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST[$quest_name]) && $_POST[$quest_name]==$option_1) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?>
```

Comment: Do not put echo inside condition.Try this instead.

`<?php echo (isset($quest_name) && $quest_name == $option_1) ? "checked" : ""; ?>`

Comment: Hi Vikas, this did not work either. Can I not do it the same as shown on www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_complete.asp except use a dynamically created variable for the radio button name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is called Radio Group. In `HTML` layer it is created with same name for all and different values for each like this:

```
<p>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="Value1" id="RadioGroup1_0">
    Radio</label>
  <br>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="Value2" id="RadioGroup1_1">
    Radio</label>
  <br>
</p>
```

And when you want to get the user input in `php` layer you go like this:

```
<?php
//check if Radio Group 1 is set
    if(isset($_POST['RadioGroup1'])) {
        // print the value of Radio Group 1 choice
        echo $_POST['RadioGroup1'];
    }
?>
```

When you want to create a Selected Radio in `HTML` layer you go like this:

```
<input name="RadioGroup1" type="radio" id="RadioGroup1_1" value="radio" checked="checked">
```

So you have to check if user inputs the value of which radio like this:

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="value1" id="RadioGroup1_0" <?php if(isset($_POST['RadioGroup1']) && $_POST['RadioGroup1']=='value1') { echo ' checked="checked"'; } ?>>
    Radio</label>
  <br>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="value2" id="RadioGroup1_1" <?php if(isset($_POST['RadioGroup1']) && $_POST['RadioGroup1']=='value2') { echo ' checked="checked"'; } ?> >
    Radio</label>
```

Comment: The radio buttons do belong to a radio group with each pass of the while statement. The first is "question_1", the second is "question_2" and so on. Four radio buttons belong to each group. I'm trying to follow w3schools' example on http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_complete.asp. My code is exactly the same except that my radio button name is dynamically created with each MySQL row data. I don't understand why I can't do the same thing as they do with this dynamic variable. And I can access what the user selected if I change the action to output to another php file but I don't want this.

Comment: I apologize, your final bit of code does fix my issue. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following:

```
<input type="radio" name="<?php echo $quest_name ?>" value="<?php echo $option_1 ?>"
    <?php if (isset($quest_name) && ($quest_name == $option_1)) echo "checked"; ?> />
```

Comment: I had already tried this. This seems logical but I don't know why it doesn't work. Provided I leave that bit of code out, the if statement in the radio button, it all works as it should.

In the first pass of the while statement it places the question on the page with four radio button choices, each belonging to "question_1" radio group. I verified it worked by posting to a separate php file and echo my selections. That all worked. I just want to post it back to itself and echo what the user selected.